# Best estimator for geometric distribution

Tags: parameter-estimation, least-squares, geometric-distribution

I need an estimator for geometric distribution $\text{Geom}(p)$ that best fits my data $X_1, X_2,\ldots$

Is $\widehat{p} = \dfrac{1}{\overline{X}}$ the answer? Both MLE and method of moments yield this estimator. However, I don't really know how to argue that $\dfrac{1}{\overline{X}}$ *best fits* my data, perhaps in a sense of ordinary least squares, but I dont know how to work with OLS with non linear distribution.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Estimator $\widehat{p} = \dfrac{1}{\overline{X}}$ is the only estimator for $p$ of $\text{Geom}(p)$. Thus it is the best fitting.

Comment: Hi: Just to be more specific about what melanie said, $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ the only unbiased estimator of $p$. Whether that makes it the best or not depends on what criteria one wants to use for best ? There are other ways to evaluate an estimator besides whether it is unbiased or not. For example, it's variance can be used.